# Need to concat two ffmpeg commands (first command video as input)

Tags: ffmpeg

First command - add overlay to my video:

```
-i test.mp4 -i img.png -filter_complex [1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v] -map [v] -map 0:a? -ac 2 -preset ultrafast test23.mp4
```

Second command slow down audio (first command video as input):

```
-i test23.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]setpts=.12*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0,atempo=2.0[a] -map [v] -map [a] test1.mp4
```

Please help me merging this as a single command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be

```
-i test.mp4 -i img.png -filter_complex [1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay,setpts=0.12*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0,atempo=2.0[a] -map [v] -map [a] -ac 2 test23.mp4
```

You're slowing down audio 4x but video more than 8x. You probably want to correct one of the operations.